# Ps4 online transfer?

Tags: psn

If I buy a ps4 from someone and they have a online for a year. Am I able to transfer his online to my account?  Because it would be a waste, but his username is dumb. I tried going to settings and looking around, but nothin came up.

Comment: Plz someone help me out

Comment: Please be patient.  Someone will be around eventually to try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't transfer the membership of PSN. Sony have stated the feature may appear in the future but give no solid timeframe.